# Buttons overlap or disappear

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, layout-manager

I have an example of a error in my program. I created 4 buttons: 1, 2, 3, 4. Button 2 overlaps button 4, and i just added events for 2 and 4.

If I
click on Button 2, it will be hidden, and Button 4 will be displayed.
And if I click on Button 4, Button 2 will be displayed, and Button 4
will be covered by Button 2 again. As if anything happened, but, when
I click on Button 1 or Button 3 after doing the above, Button 4 will
be displayed, when I point at it (not click), it will disappear.

```
public class UI extends JFrame {

    public UI(String title) {
        Container container = this.getContentPane();
        container.setLayout(null);

        JButton btn1 = new JButton("1");
        btn1.setBounds(10, 10, 50, 50);
        btn1.setBackground(Color.RED);

        JButton btn2 = new JButton("2");
        btn2.setBounds(10, 70, 50, 50);
        btn2.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

        JButton btn3 = new JButton("3");
        btn3.setBounds(10, 130, 50, 50);
        btn3.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    
        JButton btn4 = new JButton("4");
        btn4.setBounds(10, 70, 50, 50);
        btn4.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

        container.add(btn1);
        container.add(btn2);
        container.add(btn3);
        container.add(btn4);

        btn2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                btn2.setVisible(false);
            }
        });
        btn4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                btn2.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        this.setSize(400, 500);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

[Single column of colored buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrejM.png)

Comment: `container.setLayout(null);` Fix that first. Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Comment: thanks for your comment, I already know that, I just want to create a program with fixed size. I don't know how to create 2 buttons overlap if I use FlowLayout or BorderLayout or something else.

Comment: **General tips:** 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used. 3) The screenshot shows a single column of three colored buttons. For a single column of components which are all the same size, I'd use a `GridLayout`.

Comment: I just want to display 2 buttons in a same position, when I click on button 1, button 2 will appear and button 1 is hidden

Comment: *"when I click on button 1, button 2 will appear and button 1 is hidden"* Either use a [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556), or only have a single button and change its state (text and color etc) when clicked. See also [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply have an error in the `actionPerformed()` methods. You need to change the visibility of **both** `JButton`s, not just one.

Here is your code. I only added two lines and they are indicated by the comment `// ADDED THIS LINE`

```java
public class UI extends JFrame {

    public UI(String title) {
        Container container = this.getContentPane();
        container.setLayout(null);

        JButton btn1 = new JButton("1");
        btn1.setBounds(10, 10, 50, 50);
        btn1.setBackground(Color.RED);

        JButton btn2 = new JButton("2");
        btn2.setBounds(10, 70, 50, 50);
        btn2.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

        JButton btn3 = new JButton("3");
        btn3.setBounds(10, 130, 50, 50);
        btn3.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    
        JButton btn4 = new JButton("4");
        btn4.setBounds(10, 70, 50, 50);
        btn4.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        btn4.setVisible(false);  // Initially we only want to see 'btn2'.

        container.add(btn1);
        container.add(btn2);
        container.add(btn3);
        container.add(btn4);

        btn2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                btn2.setVisible(false);
                btn4.setVisible(true);  // ADDED THIS LINE
            }
        });
        btn4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                btn2.setVisible(true);
                btn4.setVisible(false);  // ADDED THIS LINE
            }
        });
        this.setSize(400, 500);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new UI("UI"));
    }
}
```

Note that although the code works without it, I think you should set the initial visibility of `btn4` to *false*. I have also done this in the above code.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a GUI where button 2 changes into button 4.

[image: JButton Example GUI 1]

[image: JButton Example GUI 2]

How did I make this happen?  Simple.  I only used three `JButtons`.

I changed the text of the second button and the background color of the second button, just like Andrew Thompson suggested.

Here's the complete runnable code.  What do you know, it's a minimal runnable example!

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class JButtonExampleGUI implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new JButtonExampleGUI());
    }
    
    private Color buttonColor;
    
    private JButton button2;
    
    private String buttonText;
    
    public JButtonExampleGUI() {
        this.buttonColor = Color.GREEN;
        this.buttonText = "2";
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JButton Example GUI");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        frame.add(createButtonPanel(),BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    private JPanel createButtonPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 10, 10));
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 500));
        
        Font font = panel.getFont().deriveFont(60f);
        
        JButton button1 = new JButton("1");
        button1.setBackground(Color.RED);
        button1.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        button1.setFont(font);
        panel.add(button1);
        
        button2 = new JButton(buttonText);
        button2.addActionListener(new Button2Listener());
        button2.setBackground(buttonColor);
        button2.setFont(font);
        panel.add(button2);
        
        JButton button3 = new JButton("3");
        button3.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        button3.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        button3.setFont(font);
        panel.add(button3);
        
        return panel;
    }
    
    public void updateButton2() {
        button2.setText(buttonText);
        button2.setBackground(buttonColor);
    }
    
    public class Button2Listener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            JButton button = (JButton) event.getSource();
            String text = button.getText();
            if (text.contentEquals("2")) {
                buttonText = "4";
                buttonColor = Color.YELLOW;
            } else {
                buttonText = "2";
                buttonColor = Color.GREEN;
            }
            updateButton2();
        }
        
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks brooo, But the comment below solved what I wanted