# I can only see the middle component in a (1,3) gird layout jpanel. Any way to fix this?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, grid-layout

I can't seem to view all three components (JTextPanel, Image, and Button) inside the a1 JPanel, it only shows the middle component (only the pic in this case). While if I delete the JTextPanel, I can see the other two components.

```
 GridLayout sold = new GridLayout(1,3);
            JPanel a1 = new JPanel();
            JPanel a2 = new JPanel();
            JPanel a3 = new JPanel();
            JPanel a4 = new JPanel();
    
    a1.setLayout(sold);
    a2.setLayout(sold);
    a3.setLayout(sold);
    a4.setLayout(sold);
    
    JPanel t1 = new JPanel();
    ImageIcon Img = new ImageIcon("images/shopPane.jpg");
    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel();
    lblNewLabel.setIcon(Img);
    t1.add(lblNewLabel);
    
    JPanel t2 = new JPanel();       
    JTextPane armor1 = new JTextPane();
    armor1.setEditable(false);
    armor1.setContentType("text/html");
    armor1.setText("<html><h3 style=\"color:white;\">· Name :"+ CessPool.armorz.get(0).name +"<br>"
            +"· Health Point : "+ CessPool.armorz.get(0).healthPoint+ "<br>"
            +"· Defence : "+ CessPool.armorz.get(0).defence + "<br>"
            + "· Accuracy : "+ CessPool.armorz.get(0).accuracy + "<br>"
            + "· Speed : "+CessPool.armorz.get(0).speed +"</h3> </html>");
    armor1.setBackground(Color.black);
    t2.add(armor1);
    
    JButton Button1 = new JButton();
    Button1.setText("Buy");
    Button1.setFocusable(false);
    Button1.setFocusPainted(false);
    Button1.setBackground(new Color(255, 238, 88));
    Button1.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    
    
    a1.add(Button1);
    a1.add(t1);
    a1.add(t2);
    this.add(a1);
```

Comment: See this [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65318746/buttons-overlap-or-disappear/65337752#65337752) for three JButtons in a GridLayout.

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Won't fix your problem but why do you create multiple levels of panels? There is no need for the t1 and t2 panels, Just add the label and text pane directly to a1 panel like you do with the button. Also, variable names should NOT start with an upper case.